# Call a bound function within a Directive from an ng-click

Tags: javascript, html, angularjs, dom

I was wondering I am able to call a bound function within a directive when part of a div is clicked. I currently have a div with another div inside that serves as a button to expand the div. The large div has a directive that makes it expandable. I would like to click on the arrow in the corner of the div and have the arrow's ng-click call a bound function inside the expandable directive. Is this possible? If so, how can I implement it?

Here's a picture of the div: 
[image]

```
<div expandable class="boxWithBorderStyle"> 
   <div class="arrowStyle" ng-click="someFuncInsideExpandableDirective()"> </div>
</div>
```

Comment: can you provide a plunker or fiddle demo

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The contents - i.e. the child elements - of the element hosting the directive have a different scope than the directive if the directive uses isolate scope (`scope: {}`), which I suspect is what you have.

In order to link the contents against the same scope, you'd need to manually transclude them:

```
.directive("expandable", function(){
  return {
    transclude: true,
    scope: {
       // whatever you have now
    },
    link: function(scope, element, attrs, ctrls, transcludeFn){
       transcludeFn(scope, function(contentClone){
         element.append(contentClone);
       });

       // here you can expose whatever functions you want on the isolate scope:
       scope.someFuncInsideExpandableDirective = function(){
          // do something
       }
    }
  };
});
```

The first parameter of the transclusion function `transcludeFn` is the scope against which the transcluded content is linked, which, in this case, is the directive's scope.

Keep in mind, though, that it is a bit awkward from the point of view of the user of your directive, since now they have HTML that refers to some "magic" variables/function (which is of-course defined by your directive) that is not apparent to someone observing the HTML. Imagine you'd encounter some directive `foo` which did something similar:

```
 <div foo="abc">
   {{foobar}}
   <button ng-click="doSomethingFoo()">do foo</button>
 </div>
```

and `foobar` and `doSomethingFoo` were defined inside the scope of the `foo` directive - it would be more difficult to decipher without knowing the specifics of `foo` what was going on.

Comment: I'm trying to follow your post above: I have changed my link function to 'link : function (scope, element, attrs, expand) ' to include an expand function I would like to call from the html. my directive returns an object where transclude = true. I am having an issue declaring the function I would like to call from the directive. So far I have 'expand(scope, function()  {alert( id + " expanded!"); });' and I am encountering the error: "expand is not a function" Do I need to declare my function else where?

Comment: Also, how do I copy my content and pass it as a var? Thanks

Comment: @hededo, `link` function has well-defined parameters that it gets called with - I, in fact, outlined what those parameters are - you can learn more about what they are [here](https://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng/service/$compile#-link-). Specifically, the 5th parameter is the `transclude` function. When you invoked the 4th parameter (that you named locally `expand`), it didn't inject an "expand" function (whatever it may be). In any case, I think I understand your difficulty, so I edited the answer to clarify

Comment: @hededo, I'm not sure what "content" you are referring to. If it is not directly related to the original question, then to avoid this being a loaded question, I suggest you ask a new question specific to your new issue, like passing content (whatever you mean by that). this will give you the proper space to explain what you want